# MySQL not converting escape character to original string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have saved the data from Codeigniter using $this->db->escape_str() in DB. It saved the string with escape character as `Altaf\'s Journey`. That's fine. But when i have fetching the data from DB, its showing the same `Altaf\'s Journey`, instead of `Altaf's Journey`.

I tried doing simply `SELECT 'Altaf\'s Journey'` (No DB Data, Its just a Select) and got the output perfectly fine as `Altaf's Journey`.

This issue is only when i am fetching the data from database. What could be the problem with this?

Comment: *It saved the string with escape character as Altaf\'s Journey. That's fine.* No. The value must NOT contain escape char.

Comment: @Akina, Yes that's fine. But issue is with fetching the data.

Comment: If you obtain `Altaf\'s Journey` in the table then you have saved `Altaf\\\'s Journey`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6937197d9f4d124453aa3647e130d1ad

Comment: No, `SELECT 'Altaf\'s Journey'` is not from DB, Its just a Select Query, If i do `Select name from table`, then i am getting `Altaf\'s Journey` as the output and the value of the name in the db is `Altaf\'s Journey`' for the same. I have updated my question also.

Comment: you only insert `Altaf's Journey` only to retrive the results.

Comment: *No, `SELECT 'Altaf\'s Journey'` is not from DB, Its just a Select Query ...* I know. This fully matches to my previous words.